# how could i implement log4j-gwt-1.0.jar in gwt example and want to know how to write log4j.properties file?

Tags: gwt, logging, gwt-rpc, gwt-log4j

when i am using log4j-gwt-1.0.jar file in build path their respective classes is not finding ie. Logger logger=new Logger.getLogger(modulename.class);
getting error. 
I also want to know how to write log4j.properties file to write log in specific file on specific location of linux file structure. please help as soon as possible. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look at this link: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging#Configuring_GWT_Logging

Answer (score 0):

**Log4j.properties**

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /usr/home/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

**log4jExample.java**

```
public class log4jExample{
      /* Get actual class name to be printed on */
      static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(
                          log4jExample.class.getName());

      public static void main(String[] args)
                    throws IOException,SQLException{

         log.debug("Hello this is an debug message");
         log.info("Hello this is an info message");
      }
    }
```

All the libraries should be available in CLASSPATH and your log4j.properties file should be available in PATH. So do the following:

Create `log4j.properties` as shown above.

Create `log4jExample.java` as shown above and compile it.

Execute `log4jExample` binary to run the program.

You would get following result, inside `/usr/home/log4j/log.out` file:

```
Hello this is an debug message
Hello this is an info message
```

For more details please go through the [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/index.htm)

Comment: i have tried this example in gwt but log file is not created. i am using jboss application server1.5v which is having inbuilt tomcat appache. so i want to ask you there is any need to install apache-log4j-2.0-beta4-bin at linux. and one more thing i want to tell you i put my log4j.properties file in WEB-INF folder. please help how could i resolve that issues.

Comment: @Ranna, I think you should remove this answer as the User is getting problem in GWT logger. It requires further configuration in GWT.

Comment: @RAS, now i am using gwt-log jar to create log file. i m following the [link](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted)      but stil i confuse how could i do that example. there is no file path configured in *.properties file.

Comment: @RAS, can you give me a complete configuration to create log file with gwt

Comment: @Baadshah:::i have create app1.log file. you have any solution.. how to get my logger.info(" test info message"); in server log or app1.log file.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using third party logging like log4j-gwt-1.0.jar anymore in GWT. GWT over the last few releases has been provding a awesome logging library. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging

You can even log [Client exceptions to Server](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging#Client_vs_Server_side_Logging) using RemoteHandler.

GWT team has done awesome job with logging. **USE IT**.

Browse Google GWT Logging Sample code @ https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/logexample/

Download Google GWT Logging Sample code @ https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.5.1.zip

Comment: ,i have configured gwt logger for remote logger in *.gwt.xml file. but i didnt get any how could i create xyz.log file on server side. please help.

Comment: i am new in GWT. i have create log file in jsp project but its not workable in GWT. please help with small example.

Comment: Hi, guys... i have create app1.log file on server side but i didnt get the my own info messages on app1.log file.